# How to add java objects into an array

Tags: java, object

I have few radio button objects and I want to add them to an array of that type. I was trying to do something like this:

```
JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton[] radioarray;
radioarray = new JRadioButton[2];
radioarray[0] = b1;
```

But its not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: By saying "not working", can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: What is the error/exception/desired behavior?

Comment: Really? Did you try to inspect the array in debug mode?

Comment: What do u mean by 'not working'. Code looks OK to me, unless 'not working' has some specific meaning in your case.

Comment: When I am trying to loop through the array I get " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException "

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating an array of size 2, and putting a reference into the first slot.  The second slot will (at this point) still be `null`.

If you then "loop through" the array trying to do something to the (supposed) `Button` at each position, you will run into the `null` in the second slot ... and that probably causes the NPE.